# MS Excel - Search Across Multiple Headers & Return Multiple Matching Values based on Corresponding Headers

Tags: excel, excel-formula, header, match, lookup-tables

Using a MS Excel formula, I would like to Search across multiple Table Headers located in Worksheet 1 (ROWS B1:I1) and Return Multiple matching Values in Worksheet 1 (ROWS B2:I9) in Worksheet 2 based on both Matching Table Headers located in Worksheet 1 and Worksheet 2.

I've attempted Index Match and Filter formulas without success... help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Try: `=XLOOKUP(A$1,'WORKSHEET 1'!$A$1:$H$1,'WORKSHEET 1'!$A$2:$H$9)` or `=IFERROR(INDEX('WORKSHEET 1'!$A$2:$H$9,,MATCH('WORKSHEET 2'!A$1,'WORKSHEET 1'!$A$1:$H$1,0)),"")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either <kbd>INDEX( )</kbd> with <kbd>MATCH( )</kbd> function or <kbd>XLOOKUP( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A2</kbd>

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('WORKSHEET 1'!$A$2:$H$9,,
MATCH('WORKSHEET 2'!A$1,'WORKSHEET 1'!$A$1:$H$1,0)),"")
```

---

Or, [image]

---

• Formula can also be used in cell <kbd>A2</kbd>

```
=XLOOKUP(A$1,'WORKSHEET 1'!$A$1:$H$1,'WORKSHEET 1'!$A$2:$H$9)
```

---

Ofcourse both formulas need to be filled across!

---

Or, Using <kbd>FILTER( )</kbd> Function.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A2</kbd>

```
=FILTER('WORKSHEET 1'!$A$2:$H$9,'WORKSHEET 1'!$A$1:$H$1='WORKSHEET 2'!A$1)
```

---

With one single dynamic array formula which spills.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,A1:E1,
     b,'WORKSHEET 1'!A1:H1,
     c,'WORKSHEET 1'!A2:H9,
     INDEX(c,SEQUENCE(ROWS(c)),XMATCH(a,b)))
```

---

Workbook link can be downloaded from **[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2cjSVpxBjQgW_VmO2J?e=N5TVoL)**

---